# Trying to figure out odd integration region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Trying to figure out how to set up integration bounds for the region bounded by $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1$ and $x^{2} + y^{2} = \left(z - 1\right)^{2}$, above the cone.  The function we're integrating is
$$
\sin\left(\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + \left[z - 1\right]^{2}}\right)
$$
That may make some difference in consideration.  I was thinking that this might best be done doing a triple integral in cylindrical coordinates.

I started to try this route and didn't get very far in being able to set up my bounds so I thought I would try to see if I'm overlooking something.

This still gives me the problem of trying to solve the radius.
Any good suggestions ?.

Comment: But what region? Do you want just inside the cone, outside the cone but inside the sphere? I'm a bit lost on what region exactly do you plan on working. Are you having trouble with the projected area?

Comment: I get that its the bottom part of an infinite cone (since its shifted), so I just flipped it upright to try and work with it easier.  I'm trying to figure out how to set it up though.  Did a similar one recently, without the shift and it seemed much easier, this one not so much.

Comment: How to set up what? This is what I'm trying to understand. I'm sorry I haven't been so clear. Do you want to integrate the function $\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2})$ on the volume bounded between the surfaces? Or are you integrating that function over the area in the $xy$-plane obtained by projecting the intersection? There are a few options I'm seeing and I don't understand which one you are after.

Comment: That function in the region bounded by the two shapes, so I'm integrating the volume of the function $sin\sqrt(x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2)$ inside the cone that gtts capped off by the sphere

Comment: just trying to figure out how to find the integral bounds

Comment: Whenever there is a question like this, the integration region should be defined by using inequalities instead of words like 'bounded', etc. In this way, we know from the very beginning how to write the integration.

Comment: I completely agree, but it was given in this way which made it somewhat ambiguous, and frustratingly irritating since both ways are certainly distinctly defined regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that since in cylindrical coordinates, $r^2=x^2+y^2$, then given the cone and sphere equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=(z-1)^2$, it follows that the bounds for the radius are $(z-1)\le r\le\sqrt(1-z^2)$. Then since $x^2+y^2=(z-1)^2$ is an infinite cone centred at $(0,0,1)$ and is perpendicular to the xy-plane, the bound for z is $0\le z\le1$.  Then, as expected, the bound for $\theta$ is $0\le \theta\le2\pi$.
Also, given the function $\sin(\sqrt(x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2))$, we can convert this to $\sin(\sqrt(r^2+(z-1)^2))$.  Observe that since $z-1$ is a function of $z$ it cannot be converted into $r^2$.  Hence the integral problem becomes:
$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{z-1}^{\sqrt(1-z^2)}r\cdot\sin(\sqrt(r^2+(z-1)^2))\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}z$.
Still not a fun integral, but much easier than trying to maintain the rectangular coordinate system and solveable in this form.